# How to make an animation that moves a formation of points using GNU Octave

Tags: animation, octave

i have been trying to figure out how to make an animation that moves this formation of points entirely together to the left (to negative x-axis direction) but i don't have any ideas. so my question is,

1. is it possible to make an animation that moves this formation of points to the left (all points move together)? if so, please explain how, or
2. is there another way to make an animation that shows all points move together?

[this is the formation that I want to animate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EEHO.png) this is the code that I use to make the formation

thank you

```
function ret = points(xL,yL,n) %n is the number of points in the formation, (xL,yL) denotes position of the leading point
  x = [xL];
  y = [yL];
  r = 0.9;
  xf = 0;
  yf = 0;
  teta = 34 * pi / 180;
  i = 1;
  while (i <= n),
    if mod(i,2)==1,
      xf = xf + (xL + (ceil(i/2)) * r * cos (teta));
      yf = yf + (yL + (ceil(i/2)) * r * sin (teta));
    elseif mod(i,2)==0,
      xf = xf + (xL + (i/2) * r * cos (teta));
      yf = yf + (yL - (i/2) * r * sin (teta));
    endif
    x = [x xf];
    y = [y yf];
    xf = 0;
    yf = 0;
    i++
  endwhile
  scatter(x,y)
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have computed the initial position of the points, you can simply plot them in a `for` loop, that is, to move the call to `scatter` in a loop.

To move the point to the left, you simply have subtract from the `x` component the amount of space corresponding to the desired movement for each step of the animation.

To set up the `for` loop for the animation, you have to define the numnber of frames and the size of the movement step; you can add these two parameters as input to the function

To realize the effect of the animation, you have to pause the plot at each iteration using the `pause` function.

You have also to fix the lower limit of the x axis at least to last x position of the left most point.

A possible implementation could be:

```
function ret = points(xL,yL,n, n_frames, frame_step,enable_gif) %n is the number of points in the formation, (xL,yL) denotes position of the leading point     x = [xL];
  x = [xL];
  y = [yL];
  r = 0.9;
  xf = 0;
  yf = 0;
  teta = 34 * pi / 180;
  i = 1;
  while (i <= n),
    if mod(i,2)==1,
      xf = xf + (xL + (ceil(i/2)) * r * cos (teta));
      yf = yf + (yL + (ceil(i/2)) * r * sin (teta));
    elseif mod(i,2)==0,
      xf = xf + (xL + (i/2) * r * cos (teta));
      yf = yf + (yL - (i/2) * r * sin (teta));
    endif
    x = [x xf];
    y = [y yf];
    xf = 0;
    yf = 0;
    i++
  endwhile

% Open a figure  
figure
% Add the axes to the figure
axes
% Get the limits of the x axis
x_min=min(x)
x_max=max(x)
% Define the number of frame for the animation
n_frames=13
% Define the step for the movement of the points
frame_step=1
% Loop over the number of frames  
if(enable_gif)
   create_gif('my_points_gif.gif',gcf,.3,0)
end
for i=1:n_frames
    % lot the points
   scatter(x-i,y)
   % Adjust the limits of the x axis
   xlim([x_min-frame_step*n_frames x_max])
   if(enable_gif)
      create_gif('my_points_gif.gif',gcf,.3,1)
   else
      % Pause the executiion
      pause(.3)
   end
end

endfunction
```

You can then call the function as follows:

```
xL=1
yL=1
n=13

% Define the number of frame for the animation
n_frames=13
% Define the step for the movement of the points
frame_step=1
enable_gif=1
points(xL, yL,n,n_frames,frame_step,enable_gif)
```

**Function to create an animanted gif**
based on the information reported in [on-line documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html)

```
function create_gif(filename,fig,delay_time,write_mode)
%
% create_gif(filename,fig,delay_time,write_mode)
%
drawnow
frame = getframe(fig);
im = frame2im(frame);
[A,map] = rgb2ind(im,256);
if(write_mode == 0)
   imwrite(A,map,filename,'gif','LoopCount',Inf,'DelayTime',delay_time);
else
   imwrite(A,map,filename,'gif','WriteMode','append','DelayTime',delay_time);
end
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for answering my question. i have tried as your explanation but when i run the program, it gives me static plot, not moving. i wonder where it went wrong. can you help me with this?

Comment: There was a bug, the following line was missing at the beginning of the function, sorry about that. `x = [xL];`. I've posted a ".gif" showing the animation generated by the code, tested in both MatLab (2015)= and Octave

Comment: That is exactly what i want the animation to be. Thank you very much, but still i am having difficulties in writing the code. When i run the program it still gives me the not-moving plot. Would you like to post the code that you use to create that animation please? i am really panicking because this is for my final project and i need to pass this class. Thank you very much.

Comment: I've updated the answer including the function `create_gif` to create an animated gif (notice the update in `points` function and in the code to call it. at present the name of the `gif` file is hard coded in the `points` function. Unfortunately, the functions used in `create_gif` are not supported by `Octave`, if you do not have access to MatLab, perhaps, you can find some workaround on the net.